# C# N-tier application - how to hide a generated EF entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 projects

```
DAL
Main
```

in the `DAL`, I create ad `DataService` class and also I generate the EF context class. How to hide that auto generated EF classes from being accessible from the `Main` project ? I want to have access only to the `DataService` class.

I cannot modify the EF entities and put there the `internal` modifier because after update the context it will be overriden.

Comment: how do you generate the context?

Comment: via built-in EF wizard

Answer (score 1):

Put the EF model and its generated classes in a separate project, reference that project from the DAL project, and then you can choose what you expose from the `public class DataService`.

Of course, if you expose entities from your EF model, and DataService is a regular .NET class instead of a WCF service, then your client will also need to reference the EF project...

If you really want to hide the entities from the client, the client is not allowed to use them at all, and you'll have to provide other ways for the client to read/write data (such as DTO's that you create in a separate project or in the DAL project).

Answer (score 1):

- Move entities to separate project
- Reference that project from the project containing your DataService
- Reference your DataService project in your main project

If you are trying to make entities ignorant of schema, use something like AutoMapper or use in-code configuration instead of .edmx